# What does "=>" mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

What does "=>" mean in the example below?

```
trait MyService[E <: Entity[ID]] extends Management {
    this: Repository[E] =>
    // some code
}
```

Comment: To the closevoters: this is neither too broad nor a duplicate (of what you linked). This should stay open unless there's a more specific duplicate

Answer (score 8):

In this example it means that `this` has to be of the type `Repository[E]`. That means that the trait `MyService` can only be mixed into classes extending `Repository[E]`.